# How to write a Vertical Right-Side IE Explorer Bar

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, winapi, browser

I've written explorer bars (band object) before and **AFAIK vertical explorer bars can only be on the left side**. However, I was amazed when I saw this explorer bar by HP that is docked on the right hand side instead:

[image: A vertical explorer bar on the right hand side]

I've searched up google for a bit and I can't find any resources on this. Does anyone know how to **build a vertical right-sided explorer bar**?

Answer (score 1):

I've just been digging into how [Kutano](http://www.kutano.com/)'s right-side bar works as I'd like to do the same. This doesn't directly help your question as I don't have an answer yet, but here's what I know:

Kutano doesn't appear to be a normal Explorer Bar, as there's no entry for it in `HKCR\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Explorer Bars`, nor does it appear in the `View|Explorer Bar` menu.

The following entries in the registry referencing the Kutano sidebar DLL:

```
HKCR\AppID\{6D6036C6-692F-4211-903B-943D94E1CCC3}
  kutano_ie_client

HKCR\CLSID\{18D81A5F-F8A5-4B78-A6CC-7E37DCAFC0BB}
  Kutano Add-on
  TypeLib {24DA2415-9F99-403F-801B-A74AE4101C27}

HKCR\CLSID\{2AE98FD7-4E58-4400-8113-B5018ED48676}
  Kutano Sidebar
  TypeLib {24DA2415-9F99-403F-801B-A74AE4101C27}

HKCR\CLSID\{2F698BD8-48CD-45B4-ACDF-67F92082EE7E}
  MenuItem
  TypeLib {24DA2415-9F99-403F-801B-A74AE4101C27}

HKCR\CLSID\{A5B02961-E212-4195-A77D-6E1346C2DE18}
  kutanoSidebarExtInterface Class
  TypeLib {24DA2415-9F99-403F-801B-A74AE4101C27}

HKCR\CLSID\{E163FD8B-2ADD-4F2E-86E8-7678D008ED43}
  KutanoToolbarBtn Class
  TypeLib {24DA2415-9F99-403F-801B-A74AE4101C27}

HKCR\TypeLib\{24DA2415-9F99-403F-801B-A74AE4101C27}
  kutano_ie_client 1.0 Type Library

HKLM\Software\Classes\AppID\kutano_ie_client.DLL
  AppID {6D6036C6-692F-4211-903B-943D94E1CCC3}
```

Some of these are more apparent as to what they do than others.

Delving about with Spy++ it seems to add an extra Shell DocObject View to the window hierarchy:

```
TabWindowClass
  ATL:63CB39A0
    Kutano_SplitterWindow
      AtlAxWin90
        Shell Embedding
          Shell DocObject View
            Internet Explorer_Server
```

It does leave the original in place and appears to continue to use it:

```
TabWindowClass
  Shell DocObject View
    Internet Explorer_Server
```

This seems somewhat different and more involved than your HP example, but hope it might glean some information to the same end. I've a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/367731dd-faf1-47f0-b538-693cdac1ab9f) about this on the MSDN Internet Explorer Extension Development forum.

Answer (score 0):

without actually creating one.. I can only assume HP queries up the food chain for IDockingWindow, sometime after setsite is called. This might allow IDockingWindow::RequestBorderSpaceDW to allocate a right side docksite.

```
IDeskBand Interface
   |
    -- IDockingWindow
        |
        --IOleWindow
find IDockingWindowSite
or   IOleInPlaceUIWindow::SetBorderSpace
from the browser window.
```

**EDIT** : from the browser document.

--

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I've played with explorer bars in the past and docking on the right isn't an option. the developers who have done this probably did it by force: injecting their HWND into the right spot and then resizing the other windows.

I suppose it's also possible they're relying on some latent feature of internet explorer that was never exposed...

I don't know why Microsoft doesn't seem to allow this type of explorer bar, but if you want something docked on the right it looks like you'll have to hack it in.